# Is there such a thing as a generic English-language news headline feed in JSON or RSS format?

Tags: data-request, json, news

I'm trying to make a mechanism which basically tells me in a few keywords what currently is being pumped out in the major news.

I could of course sit and try to determine which websites currently are the biggest and see if they might have RSS feeds, and deal with all that, and then perpetually keep myself updated as they come and go, etc.

However, that's a huge amount of work which I'd like to avoid if possible.

Is there a single RSS feed or JSON blob somewhere which is constantly updated with all those news sources' headlines in one single computer-parseable feed?

I don't care about the article contents -- just the headlines. In fact, I won't even be reading or storing the headlines, but simply extract keywords from them and store those to see which ones are the most frequent, etc.

Of course, there's always a trust issue with this third party. What if they modify/suppress/add to the headlines in subtle ways? Still, the thought of manually even visiting those websites, let alone finding the RSS feeds, is just a monumental task. We're talking about thousands of major news sources, after all.

(Plus points if it also has a separate feed for other languages than English as well.)